# jQuery - setInterval with $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am about to rip my hair of the head. I'm trying to interact with my PHP function, which is measuring some times: timeSince() a post is posted.

I do NOT need a plugin for doing this in jQuery, thanks :o)

But I wan't to run the $.get() on all .post-box-time div's so therefore I am using $.each. But it's only updating the last element, but giving me the result for the other divs to.
-> It's like it's not doing the $.each()..

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
        $('.post-box-time').each(function() {
            var time = $(this).attr('data-time');
            $this = $(this);

            $.get("sys/calls.handler.php", { do: 'timeSince', data: time },
                function(data){
                    $this.html(data);
                });
        }); // each function
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: If you open the console, do you see multiple outgoing request? (the same amount as the quantity of .post-box-time?

Comment: There's 2 .post-box-time and both of them is fired I see.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work.

Comment: For me to see that is not my problem. It's working by putting var in front of $this... $(this) doesn't work at all. Nothing is returned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you should throw a `var` before declaring `$this`.

You were declaring it as a global variable as opposed to declaring it inside the scope (which is what var does) of each function being run by `each()`.So when your response callback was actually being fired off, your loop had already completed and set global variable `$this` (or `window.$this`) to the value of the last .post-box-time it found while looping via each()

Comment: @Kolind Without the `var`, `$this` is declared as a global rather than a local variable. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Awesome. Thanks a lot for this :) Amazing that 'var' can turn the whole function to work. I love programming :)

Comment: You were declaring it as a global variable as opposed to declaring it inside the scope (which is what `var` does) of each function  being run by `each()`. So when your response callback was actually being fired off, your loop had already completed and set global variable $this (or `window.$this`) to the value of the last `.post-box-time` it found while looping via `each()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option. This [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237553/jquery-ajax-call-within-an-each-loop)  is related with your question.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

I think this within the each function is a reference to the raw DOM element. The .each gives indexes starting from 0, so you should do `$('.post-box-time:eq(' + i + ')')` instead.