# Jquery each not continuing after ajax $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My jQuery each seems to be stopping until the ajax request has loaded.
What is the problem here I thought ajax was async?

code:

```
$('div').each(function(){

    if($(this).attr('id')){
        var that = this;
        $.post('application/views/dashboard/dashboard.php?component='+$(this).attr('id')+"&settingid="+settingId, function(response){
            $(that).html(response);
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        });
        settingId++;
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a limit to the number of simultaneous calls. How many are you trying to send?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie 4 but the second is a slower call and then it won't execute call 3 and 4

Comment: Do you need to run in parallel or sequentially, or "don't care, just tell me when they are all done"?

Comment: well I just want the responses to be placed in a div and when 1 response is taking langer the divs html is loading... but if one response takes long to load the each stops and waits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.when` will wait on all async calls to complete (order and timing unimportant), then can perform a single extra operation at the end (in addition to the individual operations). You will need to use `$.ajax` instead of the simpler `$.post`:

```
var requests = [];
$('div').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id')) {
        var that = this;
        requests.push($.ajax({
            url: 'application/views/dashboard/dashboard.php?component=' + $(this).attr('id') + "&settingid=" + settingId,
            type: "post",
            success: function (response) {
                $(that).html(response);
            }
        }));
    });
    settingId++;
});
$when(requests).then(function () {
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

`$.when` works by taking an array of jQuery promises (in this case ajax promises) and awaiting a success from them all.

*apologies for any typos in the above code. I just wrote is direct into the answer :)*

You can of course simplfy the code from this:

```
$('div').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('id')) {
```

to this:

```
$('div[id]').each(function () {
```

Comment: Hang on while I fix some of the {}() errors and I'll try it out

Comment: Hmm still getting the same outcome if request 2 is loading 3 and 4 aren't being executed. if 2 has loaded 3 and 4 will execute.

Comment: Your browser is only processing 2 request at a time (max) so that is expected. What would you like to happen with the 4 results?

Comment: they're being displayed in a table

Comment: Can't do better than 2 at a time. You can change the priority/order, or make them *all* load sequentially, but not load all 4 at once. Would it help if you just show all 4 results at the end of all loads?

Comment: oh one last thing it looks like my browser is only executing 1 request instead of 2

Comment: The number of requests is browser, but 1 seems a bit ridiculous. Run the F12 Chrome browser tools (network tab) or Fiddler2 and see what is going on at the raw request level.

Comment: Well it just looks like the .each is halted until the ajax request is finished

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904704/jquery-ajax-solution-inside-each-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237553/jquery-ajax-call-within-an-each-loop). It is two different solutions.

It's just rewrite all your response. Try to store them in array, or use async: false, which make all your request work in queue.

Comment: Never suggest `async: false` as a solution! That is a really bad idea and leads to far more problems than it solves.

Comment: I agree with that, but is is one of possible solutions, and sometimes it work.

Comment: Always best to find out the actual cause of the problem. *Anything* is a better solution than `async: false`. You first link is a good answer though.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie have you mentioned word 'different'?

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax() instead of $.post. As, it has got lot many configurable paramenters.
Here you can use Promise pattern.